# Parse Javascript SDK: After query can't get object methods to work

Tags: methods, parse-platform

Has this happened to anyone? None of the Parse.Object methods are working for me. 
Globally I defined the following:

```
var object = Parse.Object.extend("Object")
var x = new object();
var query = new Parse.Query(object);
query.equalTo("somekey", "someValue");

function someFunction() {
query.first({
    success: function(x) {
        x.remove("differentKey","differentValue");
        x.save();
}
})
}
```

my terminal tells me that x.remove is false.

Why is this? How do I fix it?

Comment: what is returned by query.first?   set a local var to the "success: function(newXobj)" and then inspect that in order to see what you can call on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Since I posted this a few hours back I understand that my object methods are working but the problem is that I want to remove multi-key object from an array by key but I don't know how to select a key to remove by in an array of objects. Any help there?

Comment: well i would consult the parse js sdk on updating objects

Comment: I can recite it but it doesn't help me with select a key in an object in an array of objects. This should be straight forward but I'm a coding newbie

Comment: All I want to do is touch the objects inside the array. array[0] doesn't do anything and returns undefined in my terminal